# CNContactPickerViewController() in xcode7 swift2

Tags: contacts, addressbook, swift2, xcode7, ios9

How do I use CNContactPickerViewController() in xcode7 swift , should I import ContactsUI framework ,Im not sure , Basically I want to show the ContactPickerViewController when a button is pressed .

Note : If you guys know know the equivalent of the above in AddressBookUI Framework in swift or objective-c Please be helpful in sharing it I will modify it to make that work in ContactsUI Framework and i will post that so that it will useful for others in future

Comment: cant use Addressbook framework cuz its deprecated in xcode7, and Im not finding any good resources on Contacts Framework since its new and Im new to Contacts framework and never used Address Book framework before.

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps:

```
import ContactsUI
```

In your code initialize :

```
let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
    [CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The code should be presented and not pushed into navigation controller else you will see a black screen on the view with a delayed animation.

Comment: If we don't set displayedPropertyKeys then what would be by-default.

Comment: "The CNContact property keys to display in the contact detail card.
All the properties of the contact are displayed if this property is not set."

Comment: When I try to push my screen is blank if I present then it working why ? Thank YOu